# Saying "Congratulations!" in German

Tags: phrase

What are the possibilities for saying "Congratulations!" in German?

Google Translate suggests "Glückwünsche", "Gratulation", and "Gratulieren". Do people actually use these as one-word phrases?

Comment: You can any of these "(Mein) Glückwunsch", "Meine Glückwünsche", "(Ich) Gratuliere", "Gratulation". Depending on context, "Alles Gute" is quite often said as well.

Comment: @Em1, I think it should be „Meinen Glückwunsch“.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Nein. Als alleinstehender Ausdruck wird mehr und mehr nur "Mein Glückwunsch" gesagt und nicht "Meinen Glückwunsch". Wenn du im Kopf den ausgelassenen Satzteil ergänzt, magst du hier grammatikalisch eine Deklination erwarten; so kannst du aber dennoch bedenkenlos die Endung fallen lassen. Stichwort: Apokope. - Ich sage ausschließlich "Mein Glückwunsch".

Comment: @Em1 Interessant. In der „Umgangsaussprache“ ist der Unterschied zwischen „mein“ und „meinen“ ohnehin gering, aber dennoch käme mir „mein Glückwunsch“ falsch vor. Bestellt man heutzutage dann auch „ein Kaffee“? [In der Tat wäre ich mir sicher, „meinen Glückwunsch“ zu sagen, könnte aber nicht ausschließen, dass jemand „mein Glückwunsch“ hört.]

Comment: @Em1 Es tut mir leid, wenn das etwas abseits führt, aber denkst Du, jemand würde „mein herzlichster Glückwunsch“ sagen und nicht „meinen herzlichsten Glückwunsch“? Ich weiß, meist wird der Plural verwandt, wodurch der Unterschied verschwindet, und es ist möglich, dass das kein Zufall ist. Es würde mich aber trotzdem interessieren. Vielleicht besseres Beispiel: „Ein großer Kaffee, bitte!“

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Ja, gutes Beispiel. "Ein Kaffee, bitte." hört man auch recht häufig. - Bzgl. des zweiten Teils: Nein, wenn ein Adjektiv eingefügt wird (welches dann auch korrekt dekliniert wird), wird auch der Artikel oder das Possessivpronomen (meistens) korrekt dekliniert.

Comment: Abschließend (wenn schon die Technik darauf hinweist): Das würde mich dann darin bestärken, dass so auffassen zu wollen, dass „einen“ gemeint ist, aber „ein'“ gesprochen wird. Spätestens da wird es aber sehr technisch. Interessant, Danke!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11891/discussion-between-em1-and-carsten-schultz)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Als Ein-Wort-Ausdruck wird nicht "Glückwünsche", sondern

```
Glückwunsch
```

benutzt, sowie das selbst gefundene

```
Gratulation.
```

Comment: Even more common is the combination "Herzlichen Glückwunsch (zu[m]/für ...)"

Comment: @marsze: Kommt drauf an. Jedenfalls wäre das keine one-word-phrase.

Answer (score 8):

> Gratuliere!

or

> Ich gratuliere Dir (Ihnen)!

works, too.